# How to see the handshaking messages of SSL/TLS in firefox using firebug?

Tags: firefox, ssl, firebug, tls

I am trying to understand the internals/working of SSL. I would like to view the handshaking, key exchange, cypher exchange, session key, etc. messages communicated. So, I thought if I enable firebug and try to visit https://www.gmail.com I should be able to see some SSL exchanges in action. I cannot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think firebug works only on the level of HTTP, but HTTPS is HTTP encapsulated in SSL. To view this you can use wireshark.